# Kendo TabStrip:how to pass a partial view with different Model to Tbstrip mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-tabstrip

```
i created a kendo Tabstrip in a kendo  popup window as it's shown here: 

   @model NeoPaie.ViewModels.GrilleSalaireVM
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
@using NeoPaie.ViewModels;

<div class="popupError"></div>

@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
 .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:430px;height:400px" })
.Name("tabstrip")
.SelectedIndex(0)
.Items(items =>
    {
        items.Add()
            .Text("Grille De Salaire")
            .Content(@Html.Partial("Gestion De La Grille").ToHtmlString());
        items.Add()
            .Text("Fiche Administartive")
        **.LoadContentFrom("Liste", "GrilleRubriqueFixe");**
    })    
)
```

in the seceond tab i want to display a **GrilleRubriqueFixe****list** : a kendo grid with its crud methode:but this Exception occured:`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[NeoPaie.ViewModels.GrilleSalaireVM]'`
isn't possible to use another Model in the second tab?? how can i fixe this??

```
`
```

there is my **GrilleRubriqueFixe List**:`

```
@model  IEnumerable<NeoPaie.ViewModels.GrilleRubriqueFixeVM>
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rubrique Fixes";

}

@section  headerView {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Edit.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Common/Edit.js"></script>

}

<h2>Rubrique Fixes</h2>


@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:500px;height:300px" })
    .Editable(editing =>

{
            editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).TemplateName("PopupEditors/PopupGrilleRubriqueFixe")
            .Window(w => w.Title("NeoPaie : Ajouter/Modifier une RubriqueFixe").Width(400).Height(350));

            editing.DisplayDeleteConfirmation("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer RubriqueFixe?");
        })
    .ToolBar(commands =>
    {
        commands.Create().Text("Ajouter").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100px;float:right" });

    })
     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read("Read", "GrilleRubriqueFixe")
            .Create("Save","GrilleRubriqueFixe")
            .Update("Save", "GrilleRubriqueFixe")
            .Destroy("Delete", "GrilleRubriqueFixe")
           .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Grille_Rubrique_FixeId))

           .Events(e => e.RequestEnd("OnKendoGridSaveEnd").Error("OnKendoGridPopupListSaveError"))
             )
             .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Grille_Rubrique_FixeId).Groupable(false).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(p => p.CODE).Width(50).Title("Rubrique");
        columns.Bound(p => p.VALEUR).Width(100).Title("Valeur");

        columns.Bound(p => p.LIBELLE).Width(300).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(p => p.RubriqueId).Width(100).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(p => p.GrilleId).Width(100).Hidden();

        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy().Text(" ")).Width(60).Title("Supprimer").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });
        columns.Command(command => command.Edit().Text(" ")).Width(60).Title("Modifier").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" });

    })

    .Scrollable()
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable
                .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
                .Type(GridSelectionType.Row))

    .Navigatable()

    )
   and my GrilleRubriqueFixe Controller:
```

public ActionResult Liste( )
  {
    try
      {

```
    List<GrilleRubriqueFixeVM> lstVM = ServiceApplicatif.GetListe().OrderBy(x => x.RubriqueId).ToList();

    //  Drop Down List des listRubrique

     IEnumerable<RubriqueVM> listRubrique = RefDataManager.GetRefData<RubriqueVM>() as IEnumerable<RubriqueVM>;

     ViewData["CodeRubrique"] = new SelectList(listRubrique, "RubriqueId", "CODELIBELLE");

     return PartialView(lstVM);
    }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        LoggerGrilleRubriqueFixe.Error(string.Format("Exception : {0}", ex.Message.ToString()));
        throw new Exception("Erreur lors du chargement.");
   }
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest)
```

{
      try
      {
          //  Drop Down List des listRubrique

```
      IEnumerable<RubriqueVM> listRubrique = RefDataManager.GetRefData<RubriqueVM>() as IEnumerable<RubriqueVM>;
      if (listRubrique.Any())
      {
          ViewBag.idrub = listRubrique.First().RubriqueId;
      }

      ViewData["Rubrique"] = new SelectList(listRubrique, "RubriqueId", "CODELIBELLE");
      List<GrilleRubriqueFixeVM> lstVM = ServiceApplicatif.GetListe().OrderBy(x => x.GrilleId).ToList();

      return Json(lstVM.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      LoggerGrilleRubriqueFixe.Error(string.Format("Exception : {0}", ex.Message.ToString()));
      throw new Exception("Erreur lors du chargement.");
  }
```

}
    `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to pass the model.children this way, pass the Id of the model you are working with (Im assuming this is a readonly model at this point), and have the controller load up the model.

Here's my example where I've got a partialview which I'll load into a tabstrip.

```
tabstrip.Add()
   .Text("P11D")
   .LoadContentFrom("Dashboard_P11D", "Vehicle", 
            new { VehicleId =  ViewBag.VehicleId });
```

And then my controller does the heavy lifting to get the model.

```
public PartialViewResult Dashboard_P11D(string vehicleId)
{
   VehicleP11DData p11d = this.vehicleP11DDataRepo.Read(this.UserProfile, vehicleId);
   return PartialView(p11d);
}
```

I've also got an example where I'm just showing a Kendo grid, so the partial view loads up with no @model statement at the top (I stuff the Id I need to get in the ViewBag), but then the grid fires an Ajax method to populate the grid contents.

Comment: :my GrilleSalaire controller then must have the Crud methode of the GrilleRubriqueFixe ??? Can you please exlplain to me step by step i didn't understand what to do excatly

Comment: Yes.  If that tab partialview needs that ViewModel, then your controller method just needs to return the model data you need.  In my example I happen to have it using a repository class.

Comment: Check out Kendo's example here.   http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/tabstrip/ajax.html

Comment: @ richardb iedit my Question ,i have changed my second tab to:**.LoadContentFrom("Liste", "GrilleRubriqueFixe");** but even that my GrilleRubriqueFixe liste doesn't show up :the tabstrip is empty and i have this error: **GET http://localhost:50990/Administration/GrilleRubriqueFixe/Liste [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 123ms**

Comment: You need to pass in the LoadContentFrom method an id as part of the route parameter.  This id is then used by the controller to load the model.  Please provide the controller method.

Comment: Finally it work even without i add the id :i have a syntaxe mistake in my View :i have now a grid in my second tab :thanks a lot richardb

Comment: in my seceond tab i have a kendo grid with a poup window to add a new object: my grid is dispalyed but when i add a new object or when to delete :i have a:**Server Error in '/' Application**  **GET http://localhost:50990/Administration/GrilleRubriqueFixe/Read** but i have the read methode in my controller what could be the problem : i had edited my post to add my read controller